# match pattern using regex

Tags: regex

I want to get everything in the square brackets in this phrase, including the brackets:

"Abcd [in brackets] xyz"

I have tried this:

re.search(r'.[.])')

but it doesn't give what I am looking for, not sure how to match the second bracket

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex expression you need is something like:

```
\[[^\]]*\]
```

See a [demo](http://rubular.com/r/dGbevs2TAQ) of the above expression.

You will need to adapt it depending on your programming language.

`re.search(r'.[.])')` appears to be python, so try:

```
>>> import re
>>> str = "ABC [in brackets] xyz"
>>> re.search('\[[^\]]*\]',str).group(0)
'[in brackets]'
```

Comment: Don't think that is very useful. You could say `\[.*\]` if only one set of brackets exist. My solution above allows multiple un-nested brackets to be searched iteratively. It is not possible to make a regex allowing unlimited nested brackets.

Comment: @ronalchn: It's possible to match unlimited nested brackets if the regex implementation supports recursive patterns. Perl does, and there's a regex implementation for Python on PyPI which does at http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex.

Comment: it works for one bracket pair but for something like:                    "ABC [in brackets] xyz [other bracket] uvw" it doesn't match the second bracket

Comment: That's because it's designed to match the first bracket only. Then, knowing the position of the first set, you search (use regex on) the remaining sub-string again iteratively. This is in contrast to a regex which greedily matches `[in brackets] xyz [other bracket]` incorrectly - which causes problems.